# Setting up IIS rewrite rule to redirect not working

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-8

I'm trying to create a rewrite redirect rule to redirect the user to a specific file hosted in the same site but served using a different domain but for some reason its not working. I've never used the IIS rewrite tool so perhaps I'm doing it wrong.

Currently I have

```
<rule name="CityAndGuildsSiteMapRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="somedomain/(somefile.xml)" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="http://someotherdomain/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
<match url="somedomain/(somefile.xml)" />
```

in **match** section you can match only url and not domain part. you can use **conditions** to match domain

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference